# Given three integers is it possible to determine if a triangle can be built with them?

Tags: geometry, triangles

I'm not good at geometry, but I'm trying to practice programming, and I'm asked to write a program that accepts three integers, and returns true or false depending if a triangle can be built using those values. I'm not asking for code or anything. I just want to know if there is any formula that could help me.

Comment: Yes. Can you determine which of the integers is the largest? Can you determine the sum of the other two?

Comment: Triangle inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$a,b,c$$ the given numbers, then it must be $$a+b>c,a+c>b,b+c>a$$

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you mean a triangle with those numbers as edge lengths.  So the numbers must be positive, and the sum of any two must be greater than the third.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the other answers your numbers should satisfy triangle inequality. You can summarize it as $$\hbox{There is a triangle with lengths }a,b,c \hbox{ iff }\frac{a+b+c}{2}> \max(a,b,c)$$.

Comment: Related to Heron's forrmula for the area of a triangle using the semi-perimeter $s:=(a+b+c)/2$.